# How to use ThreadPoolExecutor with an Excel file as input and scrape date from a website

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, openpyxl, concurrent.futures

I'm trying to input zip codes taken from a predefined excel file into a website to fetch populated results and write them back to the same file in a new column. To be specific, each zip code should produce a household number, which is what I want to record and enter in the final column of the excel file.

With my current attempt, the script is doing fine. What I wish to do now is apply `concurrent.futures` library within the script to make it faster.

```
import concurrent.futures as futures
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8',
    'referer': 'https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/60634/'
}

link = 'https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/{}/'

def get_content(company,url):
    res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    household = int(soup.select_one("th:-soup-contains('Occupied Housing Units') + td").get_text(strip=True).replace(",",""))
    company.offset(0,3).value = household
    return household

if __name__ == '__main__':
    wb = load_workbook('input.xlsx')
    ws = wb['result']
    for company in ws['B']:
        if company.value == "Zip Code": continue
        if not company.value: break
        content_url = link.format(company.value)
        print(get_content(company,content_url))
    wb.save('input.xlsx')


# if __name__ == "__main__":
#     wb = load_workbook('input.xlsx')
#     ws = wb['result']
#     with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
#         future_to_url = {
#             executor.submit(get_content, company, link.format(company.value)): company for company in ws['B']
#         }
#         futures.as_completed(future_to_url)

#     wb.save('input.xlsx')
```

[Here](https://filebin.net/l6cc45s1dfm6befd) is the excel file for your consideration and [this](https://ibb.co/k859hZL) is how it looks like.

Comment: My guess: Don't involve the cell in the `get_content` function, just use the value, collect all the future results, and only afterwards write them to the workbook.

Comment: Is this for learning purposes, or do you have an actual real reason (i.e. business reason) to reach an end result, and if so, what is that end result - what exactly are you trying to achieve? Please be specific.

Comment: You perhaps failed to notice that I've started my question with a solution @Barry the Platipus.

Comment: No @robots.txt, that is not a solution to your multithreading question. Nonetheless, you got your answer now. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about trying this?

Note: I've refactored your code for clarity and simplicity.

```py
import concurrent.futures as futures

import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,bn;q=0.8',
    'referer': 'https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/60634/'
}


def get_content(url: str) -> int:
    return int(
        BeautifulSoup(session.get(url, headers=headers).text, "lxml")
        .select_one("th:-soup-contains('Occupied Housing Units') + td")
        .get_text(strip=True)
        .replace(",", "")
    )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    df = pd.read_excel('input.xlsx')
    with requests.Session() as session:
        with futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=6) as executor:
            future_to_url = {
                executor.submit(
                    get_content,
                    f'https://www.unitedstateszipcodes.org/{zip_code}/'
                ): zip_code for zip_code in df['Zip Code']
            }
            futures.as_completed(future_to_url)
    for future in future_to_url:
        df.loc[df['Zip Code'] == future_to_url[future], 'Total households'] = future.result()
    print(df.to_markdown(index=False))
    df.to_excel('output.xlsx', index=False)
```

This should print:

```
| State   |   Zip Code |   High Speed |   100M |   Total households |
|:--------|-----------:|-------------:|-------:|-------------------:|
| IL      |      60618 |        32198 |   3038 |              35407 |
| IL      |      60647 |        29868 |   3526 |              34330 |
| IL      |      60641 |        18340 |   1811 |              24770 |
| IL      |      60634 |        17743 |   1544 |              25712 |
| IL      |      60402 |        14554 |   1533 |              21338 |
| CA      |      95969 |        12074 |      0 |              12475 |
| NC      |      28269 |        13071 |    209 |              27076 |
| TX      |      78245 |        10094 |    326 |              17691 |
| IL      |      60622 |        15794 |   6519 |              24124 |
| IL      |      60630 |        11730 |   1852 |              20497 |
| CA      |      90280 |        12637 |     92 |              23278 |
| CA      |      90026 |         9878 |    191 |              24956 |
| TX      |      78207 |         9140 |     14 |              15851 |
| CA      |      94112 |        11608 |   2129 |              21975 |
| TX      |      78228 |         8957 |    147 |              18890 |
| CA      |      90201 |         7450 |     11 |              24104 |
| FL      |      32828 |         7586 |    338 |              20057 |
| GA      |      30043 |         9045 |    189 |              25997 |
| GA      |      30349 |        10507 |    656 |              25422 |
| FL      |      33027 |         7457 |     54 |              21028 |
```

And you should also get an Excel file `output.xlsx` with the same data as above.

Comment: It is faster than I ever thought. I'm having trouble understanding this line `df.loc[df['Zip Code'] == future_to_url-------`. Would you mind clarifying it in a comment? Thanks.

Comment: `df.loc` is a way to access a group of rows and columns by label(s) or with a boolean value, and that's exactly what's happening here. I find the row by zip and then pair it with another value (the result) and in this case is the number of occupied households.